# Steam Backup - exact copy of game directory?

Tags: steam, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I need to reinstall my system and and want to do a completely new clean install. I have everything backed up except Steam.

I tried many mods over the years and ended with my own favourite mix for Elder Scrolls Morrowind. I also edited config file, replaced some texture files etc.

My question is; if I use the backup feature in Steam to create backup of my Morrowind settings, does it preserve everything inside Morrowind folder - mods, saves, modified ini files etc so when I restore from backup could I use my own modified version the way I left it when making the backup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Steam backup will not pick up any files that aren't part of the vanilla game. I've just tested this. The good news is that you don't need to use Steam backup at all, just move the entire steamapps directory to a different drive, then copy it back after you've installed Steam on the new OS. It will pick up all of your games automatically.